# Magento custom module admin 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, module

I have created a module magento admin... But i found a problem..

My magento print the text, but don't fill in value, and when im post it, the multiselect return a empty array.

The multiselect:

[image: The multiselect]

The value:
[image: The value]

My form:

```
protected function _prepareForm() {
    $form = new Varien_Data_Form();

    $this->setForm($form);

    $fieldset = $form->addFieldset('associar_form', array (
        'legend' => 'Informações do ramo'
    ));

    $fieldset->addField('name', 'text', array(
            'name' => 'name',
            'label' => 'Ramo de Atividade',
            'class' => 'required-entry',
            'required' => true,
    ));
    $fieldset->addField('id_erp', 'text', array(
        'name' => 'id_erp',
        'label' => 'ID ERP',
        'class' => 'required-entry',
        'required' => true,
    ));

    $fieldset->addField('website_id','select', array (
        'name' => 'website_id',
        'label' => 'Web Site',
        'class' => 'required-entry',
        'required' => true,
        'values' => Mage::getSingleton('core/resource_website_collection')->toOptionArray(),
    ));
    $fieldset->addField('entity_id', 'multiselect', array (
        'name' => 'entity_id[]',
        'label' => 'Entity Id',
        'title' => 'Entity Id',
        'index' => 'entityid',
        'class' => 'required-entry',
        'required' => true,
        'values' => Mage::getSingleton('integravet_ramo/resource_ramo_collection')->toOptionArray()
    ));


    if(Mage::registry('associar_data')) {
        $form->setValues(Mage::registry('associar_data')->getData());
    }

    return parent::_prepareForm();
}
```

}

Collection:

```
class Integravet_Ramo_Model_Resource_Ramo_Collection extends Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Collection_Abstract {
public function _construct() {
    parent::_construct();
    $this->_init('integravet_ramo/ramo');
}
```

}

Resource/Ramo:

```
<?php
class Integravet_Ramo_Model_Resource_Ramo extends Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract {
    public function _construct() {
        $this->_init('integravet_ramo/ramos', 'entity_id');
    }
}
```

Model

```
<?php
class Integravet_Ramo_Model_Ramo extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract {
    public function _construct()
    {
        parent::_construct();
        $this->_init('integravet_ramo/ramo');
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add the code of your option array `Mage::getSingleton('integravet_ramo/resource_ramo_collection')->toOptionArray()`

Comment: Hi @AbhishekPanchal, i've updated

Answer (score 0):

i fixed it adding this method in my collection.php:

```
    public function toOptionArray()
{
    return $this->_toOptionArray('entity_id', 'name');
}
```